# How to connect UIView outlets to a custom subview

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm still new to xcode / iOS and have the following problem:

in order to display some mobile debug information, I have a UIview added/connected as outlet-property to one of my Viewcontroller. This view is a custom subclass of UIview. Now I addeddd some UIlabels as sub views to this view and want to drag the outlet connections from these labels to my customUIview.h file in order to have these labels accessible as properties of my custom UIview class (no need to access them directly from the view Controller).

Problem is that the interface builder (I'm using Storyboards/ xcode4.3) does not make the trick. I can connect the outlets to the ViewControllerClass.h but not to my sub view's .h file.
Can anyone point out where the problem is?

Comment: Would be helpful to see the `IBOutlet` declarations.  Are they of type `UILabel`?

Answer (score 26):

Just solved the problem. After typing the property outlet declarations manually in the customview.h file I could ctrl-drag-connect them from there to their corresponding UIlabel objects in the interfacebuilder. Works only in this direction!

Thanks anyway

Comment: Not sure if something has changed in Xcode since you posted this, but I was only able to do this by dragging *without* the CTRL key held down from the outlet in the Objective-C file to the view on the storyboard. If I held down the CTRL key, I'd just get a context menu when I clicked the outlet icon in the code file.

Comment: Only worked for me when dragging to the actual interface/storyboard view, not the list of interface objects on the left in IB.

Comment: I've ran into this problem in XCode 7 where apparently it still persists, and this was the solution! (dragging from the class' IBOutlet's outlet pip to the file). Worked for both the view in the IB as the list of interface objects for me.

Answer (score 1):

Update your custom view class from "UIView" to your "Custom View" class in interface builder.
And now you can make connections just by ctrl+drag your buttons or textfield to your appropriate custom class.

Comment: This seems to work for custom prototype `UITableViewCell`s, perhaps due to some magic specific to them, but it didn't work for me for arbitrary `UIView` subclasses. For them, I had to use the answer posted by tib.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Due to an interesting SO post from three years ago (about connecting to subviews of UIView), I discovered that one merely drags (not Ctrl_drag!) from the action or outlet circle (in the .h file) to the control and that's it. Works perfectly even when the controls are in a different view from the subclassed UIView. Works equally well with outlets as with actions though you always drag away from the circle.