# In IB, Cannot Connect IBOutlet Delegate to Another View Controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, interface-builder, storyboard

I have a view controller which as one of its views a container view (in IB storyboard) which embeds a table view controller, which in turn has a container view that embeds yet another view controller. In this last view controller I set up a delegate protocol with a weak synthesized delegate property as an IBOutlet. The very first view controller is what I want to receive the delegate methods from the last and I added the protocol <...> to it.

The problem is that I have not figured out a way while in storyboard (or otherwise) to link the IBOutlet delegate of the last view controller to the first view controller which follows the protocol so the last can send the first messages. I thought I could just drag and drop (with the control key) but all I find is segue options on the destination. It seems even though the delegate appears in the outlet connections window, it will not connect to ANY view controller in my project.

Can't ANY view controller be a delegate of another's protocol? And can be linked in IB? If I cannot do it with IB, I don't know how to make another VC a delegate upstream.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot connect IBOutlets between view controllers. You need to do it in code. You'll have to go through the chain of childViewController to get from the first controller to the last -- if I understand your structure properly, from the first view controller:

```
    LastController *last =  ((UIViewController *)self.childViewControllers[0]).childViewControllers[0];
    last.delegate = self;
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can also initiate by the scene name

Comment: @vectorquake, what do you mean by initiate?

Comment: Didn't think of using childViewControllers, thanks. What I did that worked was to create a property on the second VC that was populated via the Embed segue and then access that from the last VC like  `([(FirstViewController *)[(SecondViewController *)self.parentViewController firstViewController] didSelectItemFromThirdViewController:self withObject:(id)object];`  but that seemed too confusing. I might just use notifications, or refactor to unify messages to the first VC.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question [Interface Builder won't allow connections to custom UIView class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918781/interface-builder-wont-allow-connections-to-custom-uiview-class/15032869#15032869) I ultimately opened a bug with Apple. After a few follow up queries from Apple, I haven't heard any kind of resolution.