# Cannot control-drag in xcode between cocoa touch uiview class and subview in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoa

I'm new to `xcode` and `iOS`.
I'm following apple tutorial, but I can't figure out a thing.

In the tutorial, when there is the need of a connection between the `storyboard` and the `ViewController.swift`, it's done a connection using the `control-drag` from the `storyboard` to the `viewController.swift`, and it works like a charm.

If I add a `subview` to `storyboard`, apple does the connection and the declaration by code in a `custom cocoa touch class` that implements `UiView Protocol`, not using the `control-drag`.

Now, given the fact that is clear to me the code writted by apple, I'm just wondering why the `control-drag` doesn't work.

I've tried to do the same thing, adding a `button` via ui and then tried to `control-drag` to cocoa touch class, and I cannot do this.

But if I do the same thing, but trying to connect it to the `ViewController.swift` it works perfectly.

Now, I'm just wondering why this happens.
Can't I use `control-drag` with a custom `UiView`?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only control-drag from outlet to view on xib, after creating outlet in code you will see a dot at the left side, you can drag from there to your view and outlet will work

[image]

Comment: So, I should add the IBOutlet by code first and then control-drag for actions?

Comment: yes, if you want to have UIView class and xib is inside some other UIViewController

Comment: thanks man, I've done this like a charm.
I chose you as the accepted answer, and up-voted. 
But I've one more question:

"why if do I try the link between storyboard and viewcontroller I can create the link from the ui to the view controller (and so this creates the code automatically), and instead if I want to do this with a custom class I have to create via code before and then link to the UI?

Thanks.

Comment: yes it is like you described that, look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15032869/4687211

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, you have to set the class name to the view controller.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom view that will have subview of it's own, you can do so using a Xib file (pretty much like a storyboard, but for only one view instead of for a whole app workflow) and then you'll be able to make all the connection you wish. Storyboard is not meant to design your customView. Connection are mainly used to provide a easy/cost-effective reach from the control grasp to it's main view's subviews (IBOutlets) or to '0 line' a  target action pattern. One exception is with the custom tableView / collectionView cell though..

Comment: Apple tutorial makes me use storyboard, and there add a view inside of a stack view.
Then it suggests to create a cocoa touch class, and link this to the subview. I want control drag from this subview to the cocoa touch class. I have no xib file. I know .xib were used before ios 5, but now in the apple tutorial I have no .xib files.

Comment: XIB file are still used sometimes, but fair less often I'll admit that :) Now what you are probably trying to achieve is to link a subview that you have added to a scene to the viewController controlling the scene. If so, it's just ctrl-drag, but make sure that you set the ViewController custom class in the storyboard, and that on the second half of the split screen shows the source code of this class.

Answer (score 0):

For connectioning between storyboard & class

you must in the
 storyboard -> customClass -> chose your class